# Which shell I am using in mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, zsh

Default shell in my mac was bash.
I have tried to change it into ZSH by command `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

Now when I am trying to check the shell type, I am getting different responses.

#### COMMAND-1

input : `echo $SHELL`
output : `/bin/zsh`

#### COMMAND-2

input : `ps $o`
output : `7655 ttys002    0:00.03 -bash`

#### COMMAND-3

input : `ps -p $$ | awk '$1 == PP {print $4}' PP=$$`
output : `-bash`

I am not sure which shell I am using.
Do I need to do something additional to change my shell into **ZSH**.

Comment: Did you logout and login after running `chsh`?  Or, at least, restart your terminal.

Comment: In the General tab of Terminal's preferences, is "Shell opens with" set to "Default login shell?"

Comment: It's unclear what `$o` does in your 2nd command - what is the value of `$o`?

Comment: Did you put `zsh` and its path in `/etc/shells`?

Comment: it was already there.

Comment: how do I additionally make sure that my `.zshrc` file is being ran? I don't see my aliases working as of right now...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

macOS's Terminal allows you to specify the shell in its preferences.  By default, it is set to use your login shell, but it looks like you've overridden it to use Bash.

In the General tab of Terminal's preferences, set it to "Default login shell," to prevent your login shell from being overridden:

[image: Terminal's settings]

Also, make sure the "Run command" checkbox is not checked in the Shell tab of your profiles' settings:

[image: Profile settings]

Comment: the general settings - as of right now 2021 december - have changed

Comment: @CharlieParker: Terminal preferences wouldn't change based on a **date**; they might change based on a **revision**, but not on a **date**.

Answer (score 106):

To see **what shell is *currently running*** - which may or may not be your default shell - use:

```bash
# Prints something like '/bin/ksh' or '-zsh'
# See bottom section if you always need the full path.
ps -o comm= $$
```

<sup>The above assumes that the running shell is a *POSIX-compatible* shell. If the running shell is [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), replace `$$` with `$PID`, which will tell you the *full path* even if PowerShell is also the default shell. If you use 
`(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path` instead, you'll get the full path *with symlinks resolved*, if any.</sup>

To see **what shell is your *default* shell**, run:

```bash
echo $SHELL
```

<sup>If the currently running shell is PowerShell: `$env:SHELL`</sup>

---

**If you need to know the *full path* of the *currently running* shell:**

If the current shell was launched directly by `Terminal.app` (or `iTerm2`), it is a *login* shell launched via the `login` utility, which causes the current shell process to self-report its binary abstractly as `-<binary-filename>`, e.g. `-zsh`; that is, you don't get the *full path* of the binary underlying the shell process.

If always obtaining the full path is required - e.g. if you want to distinguish the system Bash  `/bin/bash` from a later version installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) - you can use the following command line:

```bash
(bin="$(ps -o comm= $$)"; expr "$bin" : '\(-\)' >/dev/null && bin="$(ps -o command= $PPID | grep -Eo ' SHELL=[^ ]+' | cut -f 2- -d =)"; [ -n "$bin" ] && echo "$bin" || echo "$SHELL")
```

Comment: how do I additionally make sure that my `.zshrc` file is being ran? I don't see my aliases working as of right now...

Comment: @CharlieParker, if `zsh` is your default shell, `~/.zshrc` should automatically be sourced in interactive sessions. You can place an `echo` command in there to diagnose. If you need further help, please create a new question post.

Answer (score 10):

Just type in any terminal you have open:

```
echo $0
```

And the name of the terminal will appear:

[image]