# Why do I have to install npm every single time I open up my terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I am following [The Odin Project](http://theodinproject.com), and I've used [this](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/curriculum/blob/main/foundations/installations/installing_node.md) guide to install nvm and node. However, I realized that every time I open the terminal, I have to reinstall everything. When I try to use 'npm', I get the message

> -bash: npm: command not found

In order to fix this, I have to do everything in the guide linked above again. Any idea of what I did wrong or is this just the way it is?

Comment: uuh, is npm in your $PATH?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Phil I'm on Mac.

Comment: @PyGamer0 I'm sorry, but what is $PATH?

Comment: How old is your mac? What OS version? [Is it using zsh or bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417162/which-shell-i-am-using-in-mac)

Comment: @Phil OS 10.13.6 and its from 2010. I'm guessing its using bash, as indicated in the quote in my post.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that sorry. The instructions you linked are for modern macs which use zsh by default. Follow the links to the [NVM install instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update) for details on getting set up with other shells like bash. You might need to delete that `.zshrc` file it got you to create. See also https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos

Comment: $PATH is an environment variable,  (meaning it is global and already set by your os), whenever you run a command, say `ls`, it  (the shell) searches for `ls` in the directories in $PATH, and executes the first one it finds.

Comment: @Phil Ok I will try that.